# Run-time error in code

Tags: c

I need to write a following function : **int64_t get_bits(int64_t val, uint bit_n, uint len);**

where *val* - 64-bit signed integer, *bit_n* - number of bit in *val* (0 <= bit <= 64), *len* - number of bits (0 < bit_n + len <= 64). The function should extract *len* bits starting from *bit_n* (numeration starts from 0). Extracted bits should be represented as 64-bit signed integer, which function should return.

That is what i got:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int64_t get_bits(int64_t val, uint bit_n, uint len) {
    uint64_t tmp = val;
    tmp = tmp << (64 - bit_n - len);
    val = tmp;
    val = val >> (64 - len);
    return val;
}

int main() {
    printf("%" PRId64"\n", get_bits(1, 0, 1)); // -1 = OK
    printf("%" PRId64"\n", get_bits(-1022, 1, 2)); // 1 => OK
    printf("%" PRId64"\n", get_bits(65535, 9, 12)); // 127 => OK
    return 0;
}
```

When I test it on my computer, it works ok (examples in main). But when I send it to testing system it has runtime errors. I think that's because of implementation defined, connected with shifting of signed numbers.
Could you give any tips how to fix this mistake?

compiler options:

```
 gcc    GNU C 6.3.0 -O2 -Wall -Werror -std=gnu11 -lm
```

Comment: Might be compier/os/hardware specific. what data can you give us about those?

Comment: What does the runtime error say? for what values do you get it?

Comment: are you sure it's a runtime error not compile time error?

Comment: The tests and errors are closed, i only know that it has runtime errors. It is given in testing system that our program will execute on x86/x64 systems

Comment: then you need to delete your program line by line and see what happens.

Comment: Run-time errors in a program that does not compile?

Comment: This can't compile as-presented. Put your `#include` stack in the posted code, and include whatever `uint` is aliasing.

Comment: Ok, i have put #include in my code

Comment: You are using uint64_t in your finction, but set it to negative value

Comment: your assumption that `get_bits(1, 0, 1)` must return `-1` is wrong I think...shouldn't it return just `1` since `1` is `00000..001` and extracting just bit 0 from it gives the same: `000...001`?

Comment: @Parket, I assume in this comment that your most significant bit (most left bit) is bit 63 and the less significant bit (most right bit) is bit 0 (correct me if you mean the opposite in your post). If `val` is 16 (64bit: `0...00010000`, only bit 4 is set), what must be the outcome of `get_bits(val, 4, 3)`? Should it be 1 (`001`, bit 4 + 2 bits to the left) or should it be 4 (`100`, bit 4 + 2 bits to the right), or even something else? Your post isn't very clear about it and your assumptions on the outcome of your 3 examples don't help in it and are probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your logic to extract len bits at bit_n I'd do it with a mask.

```
int64_t get_bits(int64_t val, uint bit_n, uint len) {

    uint64_t mask;
    mask = ((1 << len) - 1) << bit_n

    return (val & mask);
}
```

Comment: then you lose half the use case when len=32-64

Comment: @user3528438 -- do you mean len 32 through 64?  How do I lose that case? uint64_t is 64 buts